# re-sizing shadow DOM elements based on width/height style of the custom element

Tags: jquery, polymer

I am trying to write a JavaScript for my custom element such that when a width/height style is applied to the custom element, the shadow DOM elements of the custom element will resize appropriately to fit within the border of the custom element.

I know that jQuery provides `$(element).height()` to get and also set the height property. I am able to use `this.$` and allow JQuery to select the shadow DOMs. But how do I select the custom element itself from inside the polymer-element script section?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking through how the polymer team build their paper-button and how they are able to automatically re-size the background animation with the length of the button. I found that CSS is able to inherit style properties from its parents by using the keyword `inherit`.

In my case

```
<style>
  img{ width: inherit;}
</style>
```

Allow me to properly define the size of my custom button normally via css

```
custom-button{
   width: 10px;
}
```

instead of resorting to using the `::shadow` pseudo-element

Looks like I really need to brush up on my CSS.

Comment: +1, looks like I also need to brush up on my CSS as I didn't expect it to be this easy! You should mark your answer as accepted.